# Can Eclipse use .so files from NDK compilation on another platform?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, eclipse-adt

On a mac OS X I run ndk which generates some .so libraries which in theory should be reusable on windows. However, when I eclipse recompile my Android project on windows I get different apk size and it runs differently than when the whole eclipse build is done on Mac.  Only building on the mac works. Not taking the .so files from the mac ndk build, and reusing them in the windows build. Its either that or something different about how macs and windows builds apk files that I don't understand. The problem with the windows generated apk is that it has memory over consumption not seen on the apk generated solely on osx.

So to clarify this (ON MAC OS X) works:

1) run ndk on osX generate .so files
2) OS X eclipse compile android app and deploy on device.
3) OS X eclipse run apk on device.

the generated apk of course runs on all devices.

This (ON WINDOWS) does NOT work:
1) on windows use .so generated on osx ndk build.
2) windows eclipse compile android app using the .so files generated by ndk on OS X.
3) eclipse run apk on device.   The apk is of a different byte count and although it loads, it now generates memory errors unlike the apk developed solely on the OS X.

Thanks!

Comment: Wait, how are you generating APKs on iOS? Do you mean OS X?

Comment: yes, OS X I'll fix that.

Comment: Do you use the same version of the toolchain? If you have different versions of the NDK SDK then the toolchains may differ.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile cross platform code (aka NDK) on OSx (MAC) and get `*.so`, `*.a` files.

After build Android project (a.e create APK) with Eclipse on Windows.

It should work.

*(I did it for Linphone Android with core written on pure C)*

Comment: ok. any ideas what could cause differences like this?  I am checking out exact same code from git, but get different results depending on whether apk is generated on windows vs osx.

Comment: for sure you have difference (not big). ON MAC (like any other linux OS) you have difference is sizes (~1-3%). Try to copy file 1K from windows to Linux and see what the delta.